# Converse to a proposition on Alexandrov topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space, and let W(X) be the specialization preorder of X, and let T(W(X)) be the alexandrov topology corresponding to W(X). I read that if X is alexandrov, then T(W(X))=X. Is the converse true? That is, if T(W(X))=X, then is X alexandrov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

For any preordered set $W$ the space $T(W)$ is Alexandrov. Hence if $X=T(W(X))$ then since the right-hand-side is Alexandrov so is the left-hand-side.

To prove $T(W)$ is Alexandrov let $\mathcal U$ be a family of open sets. Then each $U \in \mathcal U$ is closed upwards. That means $$a \in U \text{ and } a \le b \implies b \in U$$

To show $V = \bigcap \mathcal U$ is open suppose we have $a \in V$ and $a \le b$. Then for each $U$ we have $a \in U$ and by the above $b \in U$. Since $U$ is arbitrary we get $b \in \bigcap \mathcal U = V$ as required.